# Sequelize.js : What's the difference between sequelize.define and model.init?

Tags: sequelize.js

The [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/getting-started#modeling-a-table) doesn't explain the difference between sequelize.define and Model.init. All it says is `Internally, sequelize.define calls Model.init`

What things do I need to consider when choosing which one to use? What are the main differences between the two and what are the consequences for choosing one over the other? It seems like sequelize.init is the preferred method in the documentation - why is that?

Comment: The difference is merely syntactic: `Model.init` favors defining your model as a class where as `define` is a method call. The former calls the latter and there are no real functional difference between the two approaches. IMO, define your models as classes and call `init` as this seems to be the favoured approach.

Comment: Providing `Model.init` just giving you a sensation of OOP as per ECMAScript 2015.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was recently wondering the same thing when I came across this question. I did some further investigation and found some additional details explained in the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#model-definition) that may be useful here.

**TL:DR**

Overall, the differences are strictly related to syntax, and using `sequelize.define` or `Model.init` comes down to personal preference. I do not believe one is preferred over the other, especially since the [Sequelize CLI tool](https://github.com/sequelize/cli) generates model definitions using the `sequelize.define` method, and it is not explicitly stated anywhere.

> Models can be defined in two **equivalent** ways in Sequelize:
>
> 1. Calling sequelize.define(modelName, attributes, options) [API documentation on define](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#instance-method-define)
> 2. Extending Model and calling init(attributes, options) [API documentation on init](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-init)
>
> After a model is defined, it is available within sequelize.models by its model name.

As you mentioned and as stated in the documentation:

> Internally, sequelize.define calls Model.init, so both approaches are essentially equivalent.

Comment: But in typescript, both return different types.

Comment: Sequelize-CLI generates model definitions using .init(), extending Model. I think both work, however the issue I have is that it receives some typescript errors (even if you're not using typescript). The error doesn't break anything but it's very annoying. using define doesn't.

I think it depends if you are a functional or OOP programmer.